# How to determine device screen size category (small, normal, large,) using code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight, android-configchanges

Currently using the below code but getting the same as normal for all Categories. Even if I go to setting and set as small also. Please help me.

```
        if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {

              Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, "Normal Size", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }else if((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)==Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {

                   Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, "Small Size", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }
```

Comment: which device you are using and its resolution?

Comment: Android version- 7.0. model- I20.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it's not working. Please check the below code in your device.

**To check small screen, atleast 320x426 dp and above** `getResources().getConfiguration().isLayoutSizeAtLeast(Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL);`

**To check normal screen, atleast 320x470 dp and above** `getResources().getConfiguration().isLayoutSizeAtLeast(Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL);`

**To check large screen, atleast 480x640 dp and above** `getResources().getConfiguration().isLayoutSizeAtLeast(Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);`

**To check extra large screen, atleast 720x960 dp and above** `getResources().getConfiguration().isLayoutSizeAtLeast(Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE);`

Comment: As mention above using getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK returning same value not from current setting display size.

Comment: Can you try isLayoutSizeAtLeast() method. Like `getResources().getConfiguration().isLayoutSizeAtLeast(Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL);`